# Projective volume form

Tags: d-modules, quantization

Upon reading K. Costello's paper on Witten genus, I wonder when, on a smooth (quasi-)projective variety $X$, the canonical bundle $\omega_X$ admits a left $D$-module structure (other than the Calabi-Yau case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If and only if it admits an integrable connection. In the projective case, this means that some power of $\omega _X$ is trivial, hence a finite covering of $X$ has trivial canonical bundle. In the quasi-projective case it just means that $\omega _X$ is flat.